# Add a Class to some items depending on inner html

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I'm working on a leaflet js map atm.

There are some items that I want to apply a class to, depending on their inner text. Seems as though two circles at a certain size just overlap. Adding some CSS in that case so they're no longer overlapping.

```
//function searches for all <text> elements within svg tags for the queryText 
//  and then appends them with the appendText
function addClasserino() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('map-marker marker-bg-condition'); // get all circle elements as a NodeList
    elements.forEach(el => {  // go through each text element
        if (el.innerText < 10) { // if the innerHTML matches the query HTML then
            elements.addClass('updated'); // add the class
        }
    })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //pass in the search text and the appending text as arguments
    addClasserino();
});
```

This is what I got so far. Doesn't seem to be working.

.map-marker.marker-bg-condition needs to be moved across a bit. Got the CSS here:

```
.map-marker.marker-bg-condition.updated{
margin-top: -19px;
margin-left: -19px;
```

}

With Leaflet JS, the zoom level changes and items are updated accordingly. This of my map showing all details at the world view, and then breaking down to state as you zoom in.

The unexpected behavior is that the css isn't applying and where bubbles are overlapping is because of this. This is the original code but I can't change it and get it to work even with an if statement.

```
getMarkerHtml: function(count, color) {
  var size = this.getMarkerSize(count);
  var hsize = (size / 2) - 6;
  var font = count < 1000 ? Math.ceil(size / 3) : Math.ceil(size / 4);
  if(count < 100) {
    font = font + 3;
  }

  var cluster_classes = [
    'map-marker',
    'marker-bg-' + (Filters.colors.profile === color ? 'profile' : 'condition')
  ];

  if(this.zoomLevel !== 'zip') {
    size = size * 1.5;
    if(petMapFilters.colors.profile !== color) {
      hsize = size / 2;
    }
  }

  if(this.zoomLevel === 'zip') {
    var cluster_styles = [
      'margin-left: -' + hsize + 80 + 'px;', NOTE: I tried this to offset on zip zoom bit it's not working END OF NOTE
      'margin-top: -' + hsize + 80 +'px;',
      'width: ' + size + 'px;',
      'height: ' + size + 'px;',
      'font-size: ' + font + 'px;'
    ];
  } else {

  var cluster_styles = [
    'margin-left: -' + hsize + 'px;',
    'margin-top: -' + hsize + 'px;',
    'width: ' + size + 'px;',
    'height: ' + size + 'px;',
    'font-size: ' + font + 'px;'
  ];};

  var div_style = [
    'line-height: ' + (size - (size * 0.3)) + 'px;'
  ];

  count = this.formatCount(count);
  return '<div class="' + cluster_classes.join(' ') + '" tabindex="0" style="' + cluster_styles.join(' ') + '"><div style="' + div_style.join(' ') + '">' + count + '</div></div>';
},
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here as I am not able to identify this myself.

The issue at hand:

[image: Bubbles overlapping (blue and red)]

Thanks.

Comment: I think if you change innerHtml  for innerText  and parse the result to a number should work

Comment: What you mean by "_Doesn't seem to be working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @alishahVis from your css I am understanding that you want to add this class when the condition satisfy ``` map-marker.marker-bg-condition.updated ```        
 am I right ? , if yes then as mentioned in your javascript code you are using ```addClass``` method which override the class name it doesnt append to your classname. In Addclass you can add this class name directly                                                                     
 ``` map-marker.marker-bg-condition.updated ```

Comment: Hi Rubendmatos, thanks for taking your time to be involved. I have tried that but it has not worked.

palasн, hi to you also. I will update my statement now with a photo.

Hi Aditya, thanks for that piece of information.

Comment: All updated. Thanks

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. If the problem is adding CSS classes depending on the text inside the markercluster symbol, the approach is conditionally choose a symbol depending on `count`. If the problem is markercluster symbols overlapping, the approach is to make `maxClusterRadius` larger.